# Jasmine Error when trying to set up controller object

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

This is the actual error message that I receive:

**Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: formsProvider <- forms <- SignupAcclaimController**

this is at the start of my test file:

```
describe("SignUp", function() {
describe("SignupAcclaimController", function () {

    beforeEach(module('CL.SignUp'));
    var controller, SignupService, $state, scope, identity;
    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$state_, _SignupService_, _$rootScope_, _identity_) {
        $state = _$state_;
        scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        SignupService = _SignupService_;
        identity = _identity_;

        controller = _$controller_('SignupAcclaimController', {
            $state: $state,
            SignupService: SignupService,
            identity: _identity_,
            detailsForm: mocks.form
        });

    }));........
```

The error occurs when trying to set controller. mocks.form has been declared above this code.

The actual controller is:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular.module('CL.SignUp')
    .controller('SignupAcclaimController', SignupAcclaimController);

SignupAcclaimController.$inject = ['$window', '$state', '$log', 'SignupService', 'identity', 'detailsForm', 'forms', '$rootScope', '$scope', '$timeout'];

function SignupAcclaimController($window, $state, $log, SignupService, identity, detailsForm, forms, $rootScope, $scope, $timeout) {
    var vm = this,   ........
```

If I change the injector functions signature to be the same as the method signature of the actual controller then expand the `controller =` to be

```
controller = _$controller_('SignupAcclaimController', {
            $window: _$window_,
            $state: $state,
            $log: $log,
            SignupService: SignupService,
            identity: _identity_,
            detailsForm: mocks.form,
            forms: _forms_,
            $scope: scope,
            $rootScope: _$rootScope_,
            $timeout: _$timeout_
```

then the error changes to :

**Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: formsProvider <- forms**

Comment: isn't there a longer stack trace? could this be because the SignupAcclaimController doesn't compile?

Comment: The error already said it. There's no `forms` service defined in this module.  `forms: _forms_` is useless and doesn't change anything, it still requires to have real `forms` service. If you don't have a real one, use a mock (your own services generally should be mocked in controller tests).